# YII2 Drag and Drop

Tags: drag-and-drop, yii2

Good night. I need to make Drag and Drop effect. I have two columns and I need drag items between columns, I can make it with Sortable widget like [this](http://demos.krajee.com/sortable)
But i need to make on this items button, to choose personal color for this items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out:
https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula

super easy and working drag and drop library!

[demo is here](https://bevacqua.github.io/dragula/)